# ImageView src not showing in xml

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview

I've pasted an image file in the drawables but it is not showing in the XML files.

In the code below the part after "src" is getting red highlights even though I've the same named file in Drawable.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/splashImage" 
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
```

Comment: There is no `src` attribute on that `ImageView`.

Comment: add this to image view  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" and see

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     **android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"**
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Make Sure that your XML file is well formatted

2- make sure that your image name doesn't have special characters then clean your project

if this doesn't work

try to invalidate the cache and restart (File -> invalidate caches and /Restart)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Clean and Rebuild the project
- Close and reOpen AndroidStudio
- Check if the format of the Image File is correct or able to read